# How do I end this process?

Tags: windows-7, process, task-manager, privileges

I want to end this process below :
[image]

But whenever I try, I get an error :

[image]

Is there a way to do this ?

The process `SAPISSVC.EXE` is actually an antivirus process.
I want to close it because sometimes I remain offline and do work (mainly on ORACLE) and there is only 2.00 GB of ram out of which only 1.87 GB usable, rest is for graphical purpose. So the ORACLE hangs. But, If I can end this process then I think that I can run ORACLE freely. And one more thing that I am not authorized to do anything with the files through which this process starts.

Comment: So this isn't your personal box, it's a school or business box?

Answer (score 2):

1. Driver-level service processes (like your anti-virus) are run by the System user, and that user has higher privileges than your Admin user.
2. Force-stopping a kernel/driver-level process is a bad idea and would probably just crash the system if you did manage to do it.
3. Anti-virus packages almost always implement further security to prevent their services from being stopped, to help prevent viruses from just turning the AV off when an infection hits.

Assuming you're an admin of the machine, either disable the AV package via it's interface, or use MSconfig to enable/disable the AV services and reboot as needed.

Comment: Actually I was able to remove that process but, in previous version of AV. In the latest version of this AV, I can't end this process.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not running Task Manager as administrator.  Try going to Start -> Accessories -> Command Prompt -> right click, run as Administrator, then type `taskmgr.exe` to launch it from there as administrator.

Where I work, we run Symantec, and the end user can, through the system tray, temporarily disable the anti-virus.  Look in your system tray to see if you have a similar option.

If you are stuck due to your workplace's IT policies, you ought to tell them you need more RAM, 2GBytes is rather low these days.  You could also shut down your Firefox which seems to be taking roughly the same amount of memory.

Comment: **Uhh huh... no luck still the same error**. And there is option to disable antivirus but the process still takes that much memory. The firefox was running when I was writing this question and taking window snips.

Comment: @MukulKumar AntiVirus tools often include a "Self Protection" which prevent other tools to kill them.